# groovy spock testing Mock and returned proxy

Tags: groovy

Spock Testing - new spock user.

Problem with using Spock in terms of mocking return value.
the classUnderTest has an apply method. The first step is to get AssetType attribute from a Term. Both AssetType and Term are interfaces.

The test fails as it seems that AssetType is not returned rather the created Spock proxy

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'Mock for type 'AssetType' named 'assetType'' with class 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11' to class 'com.collibra.dgc.core.model.meta.AssetType'



public Errors apply(){

     def at=t.getType()
      ...
  }



import spock.lang.Specification

import com.collibra.dgc.core.component.representation.TermComponent;
import com.collibra.dgc.core.component.relation.RelationComponent;
import com.collibra.dgc.core.model.representation.Representation
import com.collibra.dgc.core.model.representation.Term;
import com.collibra.dgc.core.api.component.assignment.AssignmentApi
impoort com.collibra.dgc.core.api.internal.dto.instance.view.table.AssetTableOutputRequest
```

import com.collibra.dgc.core.api.model.meta.type.AssetType
import com.collibra.dgc.core.model.representation.Representation;

```
class CustomExceptionRuleValidator1Spec  extends Specification{

Term term=Mock()
AssetType assetType=Mock()

def """If validate"""() {

    given:
    RelationComponent relationComponent=Mock();
    TermComponent termComponent=Mock();
    AssignmentApi assignmentApi=Mock()
    ConceptType dataElementConceptType=new DataElementConceptType(assignmentApi)
    ConceptType.register(dataElementConceptType)
    CustomExceptionRuleValidator classUnderTest=new CustomExceptionRuleValidator(relationComponent,termComponent);
    classUnderTest.withTerm(term)

    when:
    Errors errors=classUnderTest.apply()

    then:

    1 * term.getType() >> assetType
    1 * assetType.getName()>>"Data Element"
    1 * term.getSignifier() >> "my data element"

    errors.hasErrors()

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Seems in the classpath there was another AssetType apart from
import com.collibra.dgc.core.api.model.meta.type.AssetType
and this caused the behaviour experienced.